# ASP.NET ListView table template not working properly (item disordered )

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, listview

I used below code to generate a table view from ListView control, after some more document load (mostly 10 item), the order of items are disturbed,

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" >
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <ul>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />    
        </ul>                
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
             <table >
                 <tr>
                     <td >
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ibtnDownload" ImageUrl='../res/i/UploadedFiles.jpg' ToolTip='<%#Eval("Name") %>' runat="server"  OnClick="ibtnDownload_Click" />
                         <asp:Label ID="lblFullName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FullName") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                     </td>

                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                     <td >
                          <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelect" runat="server" style="margin-right:1px;"  />

                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkFileName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>' OnClick="ibtnDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton></td>

                 </tr>

             </table>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <p style="font-weight:bold; margin:50%; width:200px;">No Files Uploaded </p>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

THe CSS used for this listview is,

```
 li 
 {
    display: inline ;   
 }
 ul li table 
 {
   float: left;
   margin-left:10px;
   width: 10em;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-align:center;
   overflow:hidden;
   color:black;
   padding: 0.2em 0.6em;
   border-right: 1px solid white;
   cursor: pointer; cursor: hand; 
 }
```

Below is the picture of result
[image: The list view is disturbed]

Comment: Any information on the resulting HTML, on the stylesheet and on the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css option `float: left;` leads to this behavior, because your items have different height. When a row is full, the next item is floating as far to the top as possible, without its upper edge floating top left the lower edge of any previous item.

The effect is, that whenever a 3-line text is followed by a 2-line-text item (in line 1 and 3) or a 4-line-text is followed by 3-line-text (in line 4), the next line item is aligned in the corner below these items.

In order to prevent this behavior, set a common height for all items.

This can be done by moving the floating-behavior from table to `<li>` and adding a fixed height there or using some dynamic (jQuery) approach to set an equal height based on the largest item.

You also have to move some other css properties to the list item, since they are related to the floating

```
li {
    display: inline;
    min-height:150px; /* set your desired height*/
    max-height:150px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Did you mean set fix height and width for ItemTemplete or set the fix width of label ?

Comment: @TahirAlvi On the list item in the item-template... see my update

Comment: Thanks a lot, now am set the fix height and width and all is going great.